# Windows server 2019 - minimal permissions to allow certmgr.msc (local) to connect to server for read cert store access

Tags: operating-system, certificate, remote-access, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to figure out what userrights or group membership would be necessary to allow normal built-in\users read-access to a remote server's certificate store via certmgr.msc (or "manage computer certificates").  As seen below, one of the users I had test from their laptop opened certmgr and selected "connect to another server", but then received "you do not have permissions to manage the certifcate store".  The only thing I've seen is possibly adding registry permissions so they can query, but that was from a pretty old winsrv2012 article that was more towards using posh to query.  I'd just prefer admins not have to stop and check server cert stores, since I'm not supposed to allow everyone RDP access.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows stores LocalMachine certificates in the registry, so your users need access to connect to the Remote Registry service, and the service must be running. By default, only Administrators and the Backup Operators group have permission.

To give access to other users:

- open regedit as admin
- Locate the following key:
  `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg`
- Right-click winreg, click Permissions, and then edit the current permissions or add the users or groups to whom you want to grant access.
- then restart Windows.

It looks like you can give `ReadKey` rights for read-only access.

---

Also note that the windows cert store allows all users to read the public certificate information, but only Administrators and SYSTEM can read/export the **private** keys. This can be adjusted per-certificate in certlm.msc by right-click the cert > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys.

Comment: Hey thanks!  I'm trying your suggestion now via AccessControlDsc

Comment: This worked great, appreciate your support.